# Java library for comparing WSDL elements syntactically

Tags: wsdl, java

I have WSDL files and would like to compare and match WSDL elements in these files syntactically. Do you have any suggestions for Java libraries that can be used finding syntactical similarities between two terms in Web (for me, wsdl elements)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [WSDL Analyzer](http://wsdl-analyzer.com/) which builds upon the most recent version of the [Membrane SOA Model](https://github.com/membrane/soa-model). It's a web application which not only allows you to validate and check your 
WSDL against best practices but also lets you compare different versions of your WSDL.

Disclaimer: I'm one of it's developers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use SOAPUI to load the wsdl definitions and compare them.

Including link with some documentation relating to your question.  Hope is of some help.

http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/working-with-wsdls.html

edit:
Also, check out http://www.membrane-soa.org, which as some libraries for comparing wsdl files.
Some specific examples are here: http://www.membrane-soa.org/compare-wsdl-java-api.htm